# adding removing html tag link on a ng-if function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

***html:***

```
<a data-ng-if="price" data-ng-click="selected(price)">
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
</a>
```

i want to remove the `<a></a>` if `data-ng-if="!price"`

Does anyone know the correct way of doing this?

Comment: What behavior you want by removing anchor element? Do you just want that not to be clickable.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want. Can you please try to explain it.

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal yes i want that not to be clickable

Comment: `ng-if` removes the element from the DOM, how exactly are you still seeing the `a` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options, first is to move inner content into a script and render it at two places:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="main-content.html">
      <div>...your inner content</div>
</script>

<a ng-if="price" data-ng-click="selected(price)">
    <div ng-include="'main-content.html'"></div>
</a>

<div ng-if="!price" ng-include="'main-content.html'"></div>
```

Second approach is that, you can use CSS to make it non clickable:

```
<a ng-class="{no-price: !price}" data-ng-click="selected(price)">
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
</a>
```

And in your CSS:

```
a.no-price, a.no-price:hover, a.no-price:visited, a.no-price:focus {
    color: black;    // normal color
    pointer-events: none;    // no clickable
    text-decoration: none;    // No link feel
}
```